# Preserve list order that comes from the intersection of more than two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set-intersection

I have the following dictionary

```
di = {
    'A': [['A1', 'A1a'], ['A1', 'A1a'], ['A1', 'A1a'], ['A1', 'A1a'], ['A1', 'A1a']], 
    'B': [['A1', 'BT', 'B2', 'B2a', 'B2a1a']], 
    'G': [['A1', 'BT', 'CT0', 'CF', 'F5', 'GHIJK', 'G4', 'G21', 'G2a', 'G2a2b', 'G2a2b2b', 'G2a2b2b1a'],
          ['A1', 'BT', 'CT0', 'CF', 'F5', 'GHIJK', 'G4', 'G21', 'G2a'],
          ['A1', 'BT', 'CT0', 'CF', 'F5', 'GHIJK', 'G4', 'G21', 'G2a', 'G2a2b', 'G2a2b2a', 'G2a2b2a1a1b', 'G2a2b2a1a1b1', 'G2a2b2a1a1b1a2']]
}
```

Note that I have more than two lists for two of these keys, and only one list for B.

For each key I want to return the intersection for each of the lists. So that it looks like the following:

```
intersection = {
    'A': ['A1', 'A1a'], 
    'B': ['A1', 'BT', 'B2', 'B2a', 'B2a1a'], 
    'G': ['A1', 'BT', 'CT0', 'CF', 'F5', 'GHIJK', 'G4', 'G21', 'G2a']
}
```

I was originally using the following to get the intersection

```
out = {}
for key in di:
  out[key] = set.intersection(*map(set, di[key]))
```

And it works, but it loses the ordering. The last element in each of those lists is the 'last common ancestor' or lca. My goal is to find the lca for each of the key value pairs across many individuals. For example, the key-value G looks like this:

```
out['G']
{'A1', 'BT', 'CF', 'CT0', 'F5', 'G21', 'G2a', 'G4', 'GHIJK'}
```

Which is wrong, because clearly the lca should be G2a, not GHIJK. After doing some digging it seems this comes from using sets. I have found lots about finding the intersection between two lists that don't require me to convert it to a set, but is there a way to do this for more than two lists?

Comment: You can't use `set` if order needs to be maintained.

Comment: Where does `A1:1` come from? It's not in the original `B` value.

Comment: The `A1:1` was a mistake on my part. I coped that value over from the wrong location. I've edited out my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create the intersection of all the sublists. Then use a list comprehension of the first sublist to find all the elements that are in the intersection, so it will be in the original order.

```
out = {}
for key, (list1, *rest) in di.items():
    intersection = set(list1).intersection(*rest)
    out[key] = [i for i in list1 if i in intersection]
pprint.pprint(out)
{'A': ['A1', 'A1a'],
 'B': ['A1', 'BT', 'B2', 'B2a', 'B2a1a'],
 'G': ['A1', 'BT', 'CT0', 'CF', 'F5', 'GHIJK', 'G4', 'G21', 'G2a']}
```

Comment: You may want to write the listcomp over the result of `dict.fromkeys(value[0])` so it's deduped (but maintains order on 3.6+), assuming the input might not be unique, e.g. `out[key] = [x for x in dict.fromkeys(value[0]) if x in intersection]` (I also changed the iteration variable name to `x`, because `i` is for indices or integers, and these are neither).

Comment: You can also avoid a number of unnecessary `set`s by changing the code to: `intersection = set(value[0]).intersection(*value[1:])` (one must be made a `set` to call `intersection` on it, but the arguments to `intersection` can be plain iterables without preconverting to `set`).

Comment: That first comment is too hacky for my taste. And it's basically doing the same de-duplication as the list comp itself does.

Comment: The listcomp isn't doing any deduplication (it can't without resorting to weirdness with side-effects to mutate the `intersection` `set` as it goes, and you definitely don't want to do that). If `list1` contains `['A1', 'A1', 'A1']` and `'A1'` exists in the intersection with the other lists, then `out[key]` will contain `['A1', 'A1', 'A1']` as well, not just `['A1']`, which I *think* the OP was trying to avoid. I did think of the `(list1, *rest)` unpacking for cleanliness after posting the comments, but didn't think it was important enough to mention; glad you went there anyway. :-)

Comment: Oh right. When I was originally thinking about this, I was going to add to the set incrementally as I iterate over the list, and use `not in` as the test, so it would de-duplicate within the list as well. Then I realized I could use the intersection in the test, and didn't rethink that part.

Comment: @Ctat41 Will there ever be duplicates within a sublist that need to be removed?

Comment: No, there are no duplicate items in the sub-lists here. Each element of a sub-list is unique within its sub-list.

Comment: You use `set` and maintain order, proving the guy wrong who commented *"You can't use `set` if order needs to be maintained."*.